# CloudWatch event rule does not trigger Step Functions state machine

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch, state-machine, aws-step-functions, aws-event-bridge

I have a problem with cloudwatch event rules

If any detail is missing please let me know

**What I'm trying to achieve:**

1. Cloudformation updates ECS service
2. CloudTrail catches the UpdateService event and triggers the CloudWatch event rule
3. CloudWatch event rule triggers the step machine

**What my problem is:**

StepMachine is not being triggered

**CloudWatch rule event pattern:**

```
{
  "source": ["aws.ecs"],
  "detail-type": ["AWS API Call via CloudTrail"],
  "detail": {
    "eventSource": ["ecs.amazonaws.com"],
    "eventName": ["UpdateService"]
  }
}
```

This rule uses auto generated role for triggering step functions.
Role is called Amazon_EventBridge_Invoke_Step_Functions_1046886785 in my case

Any kind of help would be appreciated